# Is there any way to change the hue of an entire webpage client side?

Tags: javascript, colors

Haven't been able to find any sort of information about this. Seems like it should be possible...

Is there any way to change the hue of an individual element (like say an image) with js?

Answer (score 1):

You can access an image's data using the canvas API. Then you can change the colours. This can be very expensive though (take a little while to render).

For doing the whole page, you could do

```
#overlay {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    opacity: 0.7; /* check IE's proprietary filter */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tint the image a specific color, you could overlay a translucent colored `div`.

If you mean actually shifting the hues of the image, as you might do in Photoshop, I don't believe JavaScript can do that in any major browsers.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible in modern browsers: you can retrieve and modify values of regions or individual pixels of canvas elements.

Comment: obviously i'm not up on what you can do with canvas.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of doing it is something along these lines:

1. Go through every element in the
   page, find it's COMPUTED background
   color and text color. Use something
   like [ColorJizz](http://code.google.com/p/colorjizz/) to change the
   hue.
2. Find every image - including
   backgrounds images. Maybe again you
   could do this by finding the
   computed styles. It'd be tricky..
   You then have the option of either
   redirecting them to a server side
   script that can change the hue of
   those, or replacing them with a
   canvas element and going through
   every pixel and changing the color
   of that. Again - colorjizz would
   work for this, but it'd be VERY
   slow.

Generally though, I wouldn't recommend doing any of this. It'd be VERY hard to get right.